# "Unsubscribe to" vs. "unsubscribe from"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Marketing emails often come with an unsubscribe link in the footer. This is what Twitter uses:

> You can also unsubscribe to these emails or change your notification
>   settings.

"Unsubscribe from these emails" seems far more natural to me because unsubscribing is an act of removal. Add **to**, remove **from**. Is there a consensus on this?

Comment: Don't expect crap you read on the Web to be grammatical, especially crap from Twitter.

Comment: I agree with @Robusto here, lot of garbage is there on web. I support him when he says Twitter is full of crap.

Answer (score 11):

Affordances and auxiliaries peculiar to one verb are often found with other words derived from it.

Since ***subscribe*** takes ***to*** as a transitivizing preposition, so does *unsubscribe*.

- *She had subscribed to it for years.*
- *She unsubscribed to it after they published that letter.*

However, since ***unsubscribe*** has the negative sense of reversing a subscription, and cutting a connection -- in other words, *moving away from* -- the general ablative transitivizer ***from*** is also sanctioned, although it's not correct with *subscribe*.

- *She unsubscribed from it after they published that letter.*
- **She subscribed from it after they published that letter.*
- *She was divorced from him shortly afterward.*

Comment: General albative transitivizer! Upvoted.

Comment: _Ab_ 'from' + _lātus_ 'taken' (perf pple of _ferō, ferre, tulī, lātus_ 'carry, take'). Very straightforward Latin. This is what happened to the ablative case nouns in Romance languages [when the cases were lost](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TheGrammaticalizationCycle.pdf); they changed to prepositional phrases with (usually) ***a***.

Comment: John, so what's the bottom line?  For unsubscribe, is "from" now the correct form, either way is now recognized as correct, or "from" is technically wrong but common practice?

Comment: There is no "technically", nor any "correct", nor any "bottom line". Language is not law, not even thought. It's just personal habits of various people with varying ideas of how to proceed. [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) may put "Which preposition is to to be used with _unsubscribe_" on its agenda, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: @MattMontag You upvoted just because he used a word you can't even spell? :-P

Comment: Here in 2020, ["subscribe from"](https://www.google.com/search?q="unsubscribe+from") is 1,909x more common than ["subscribe to"](https://www.google.com/search?q="unsubscribe+to") based on exact phrase searches on Google.